# Sistema de Login - HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estou fazendo um sistema de login, porém ao submeter os dados ele da HTTP ERROR 500. Tentei mudar de todas as formas o código mas esse erro continua. Estou usando o 000webhost para testar como está ficando o site, será que esse servidor que não tem suporte aos códigos que usei ou tem algo errado no código e não estou percebendo?

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("conecta.php");
if ((isset($_POST['email'])) && (isset($_POST['senha']))) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);
    $senha - md5($senha);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM voluntarios WHERE email = '$email' and senha = '$senha'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if (empty($resultado)) {
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "E-mail e/ou senha inválidos!"
        header("Location: entrar.php");
    } elseif (!empty($resultado)) {
        header("Location: indexVol.php");
    } else{
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "E-mail e/ou senha inválidos!"
        header("Location: entrar.php");
    }



} else {
    $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "E-mail ou senha inválidos!";
    header("Location: entrar.php");
}
?>
```

Conexão com o banco de dados:

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "arthur", "senha","banco");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Falha na conexão: " . mysql_connect_error());
} else {
    //echo "Conexão realizada com sucesso";
}
?>
```

Comment: Como que funciona esta linha? "$senha - md5($senha);"

Comment: @WictorChaves Essa linha é para criptografar a senha, mas esse - está errado, era pra ser =, vou ver se era esse o erro mesmo!

Comment: Faltam os ponto-e-vírgulas (`;`) quando você define as sessões. E você utilizou a função `mysql_connect_error` ao invés de `mysqli_connect_error`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu mudei isso, não da mais o erro, porém ele não vai pra página indexVol.php ele apenas fala que o email e a senha estão errados, porém está igual do banco de dados

Comment: Então verifique o valor de `$resultado` fazendo `var_dump($resultado)`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu coloquei mas não apareceu nada.